# Error : in my query i am using multiple variables in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i am not getting what is the issue in the query probably i am not following the correct way to put the string and char sign , i am inserting the data in c# to local host with where clause please check the query and Error i am getting

Here is the query

```
String insertQuery = "insert into exam_add (id,session_id,Title,From_date,To_date,class_id,is_Post,is_Lock) select '"+id+ ",s.session,'" + title.Text+",'"+ from.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+",'"+to.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+ ", c.class_name,'"+x+",'"+x+" from year_session s, classes c where s.id = '1' and c.id='" + cls + "'";
```

Exception image
[here the image for exception i am getting after run this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFT2h.jpg)

Comment: I think you should fix your giant SQL Injection attack vectors first, by using parameterized queries.

Comment: i think the query is correct but the signs are not on correct positions

Answer (score 0):

On your ...'"+x+"... you forgot to close the single quotes. You open them but you never close them after you add the X variable to your query. All SQL is seeing is "'0," which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use SQLparameters to avoid sql injection but your error is you forgot to close the single quotes it shoud be like this `'"+cls + "'`

```
 String insertQuery = "insert into exam_add (id,session_id,Title,From_date,To_date,class_id,is_Post,is_Lock) select '" + id + "','"+s.session+"','" + title.Text + "','" + from.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','" + to.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' , '"+c.class_name+"','" + x + "','" + x + "' from year_session s, classes c where s.id = '1' and c.id='" + cls + "'";
```

I don't know why you need that on select columns. and  you provided insufficient information and code on your question.

Comment: can you please re-write it for me i have tried but still getting the error

Comment: i say it pretty staright forward any way i update my code. pls accept as correct answer if it helps you.